# OGR/GDAL & Python: Get Feature by Attribute

Tags: python, gdal

First entry here after years of reading. Yay.

I have a SHP with two Polygons. There is a column *id*, where the 2 SHP have the value *1* and *2*.

I now try to access the feature via the id:

```
70 all_geoms = []
71 feature = layer.GetFeature(polygonID)
72 geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
73 all_geoms.append(geometry.Clone())
```

polygonID is the user given ID for the polygon.

Unfortunately, I'm only able to access the features via 0 and 1. When trying to retrieve Polygon 2 the following error occures:

```
File "hypsometric.py", line 72, in <module>
geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetGeometryRef'
```

How can I tell GDAL, to get me a feature by a given column-value?

Comment: please add the line where this appears. (the one with `GetGeometryRef`) Also note: `NoneType` error is usually an issue somewhere earlier in the code,  so we need more code to be able to help.

Comment: Edited the start post.
The error doesn't occur, when i set polygonID to 0 or 1. It seems to take the first feature as 0, but the id column starts with 1